# commerce feeds product import not showing up

Tags: feeds, commerce

I imported a file with 5 fields *UPC-> SKU(Unique), Product Description -> Title, Unit Price -> Price Amount* and 2 custom fields for wood type and knife number the import process says it created 21 products and I can find these products through *phpmyadmin* in various places including *commerce_product, commerce_product_revision*.

There are also a number of entries of type *commerce_product* in the *field_revision_field_product_category* table where as the types of my already created content are node in the same table. They all have a price of 0  but are not showing up in the product listing.

I'm using [commerce kickstart 2.0](https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2), [commerce feeds 1.3](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds), f[eeds 2.0 alpha 7](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and have [feeds tamper 1.0 beta 4](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper). 
I have run cron and flushed all caches.

I tried this in a fresh install of [Commerce Kickstart](https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2) but the products are still not showing up in the *view products* screen.

I also created a *barebones Drupal 7* install with commerce and [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)/[commerce feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) and other required modules and the products seem to be created just fine.

Comment: You created products, but no product displays.
That's why Kickstart is not showing anything.
Kickstart 2.6 now has an "all product variations" view where you can see just the products.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday on #drupal-commerce in IRC, someone had a similar question. It appears that the "title" module may be interfering with commerce_feeds. Try disabling the "title" module and see if that helps your import woes.

Comment: Still got nada removed tamper module too

Answer (score -1):

It seems Bojan Zivanovic is right. I don't see anything about a second importer to create the nodes. You'll need two importers and need to specify what gets added to the product (variation) and what gets added to the node (content type).

Comment: Did you solve this? I guess I must have been unclear as to your question. Does this indicate you did in fact create (and import) to the content type / node: "as the types of my already created content are node in the same table"?

If you create a product manually does it show up? Can you confirm your importer settings?